# JavaScript Date not working properly in IE8

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Chrome showing result as expected but IE-8 giving NAN when i execute the following:

Chrome:

```
d = new Date("2014 12 01") // results Mon Dec 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
```

IE-8:

```
d = new Date("2014 12 01") // results NaN undefined
```

Comment: `Date` has nothing whatsoever to do with jQuery

Comment: @RohitArora: No, because that's about parsing the format that the specification added in ES5. This is about parsing a random non-standard format.

Comment: That's because Chrome is smarter and less strict than IE8. "2014 12 01" is all but a correct date format. Chrome is just smart enough to understand it nonetheless, but strictly speaking, it shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format you're trying to parse doesn't match [the only specific format that `new Date` is required to parse](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15). To parse it reliably cross-browser, you need to parse it explicitly — either in your own code, which can be trivially done with a regex, or using a library like MomentJS and telling it what the format is.

The trivial regex solution:

```js
// NOTE! Uses local time.
var yourString = "2014 12 01";
var parts = yourString.match(/^(\d{4}) (\d{2}) (\d{2})$/);
if (parts) {
  var date = new Date(+parts[1], +parts[2] - 1, +parts[3]);
  alert(date.toString());
}
```

Comment: what magic is the `+` doing in the final `new Date(...)` call doing? or is it redundant?

Comment: @scunliffe: No magic :-) It's converting the strings into numbers.

Comment: Ah yes (doh) they're still strings coming out of the RegEx...